# Bash input the data from a text file and process it

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a bash script which will take entries from a text file and process it based on the requirement.

I am trying to find out the last login time for each of the mail accounts. I have a text file email.txt contains all the email addresses line by line and need to check the last login time for each of these account using the below command :

```
cat /var/log/maillog | grep 'mail1@address.com' | grep 'Login' | tail -1 > result.txt
```

So the result would be inside result.txt

Thanks,

Comment: And what is the problem with that command line?

Comment: we cannot see your screen. please describe what does your input file look like, what output do you want to have.

Comment: Useless use of `cat` spotted!

Comment: I need a script to take the email.txt file which contains email addresses like :

a1.example.com
a2.example.com

Each email address in a new line.. and pass to the command I put in the question

Comment: Post a sample of your `email.txt` file.

Comment: @Gopu, replace `/var/log/maillog` with `/path/to/email.txt`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
while read email_id ; do grep "$email_id" /var/log/maillog   | grep 'Login' >> result.txt ; done < email.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the email addresses in parallel (rather than repeatedly scan what is probably a very large log file).

```
grep -f  file_with_email_addrs /var/log/maillog
```

Weather this is worthwile depends on the size of the log file and the number of e-mail addresses you are getting. A small log file or a small number of users will probably render this mute. But a big log file and a lot of users will make this a good first step. But will then require some extra processing.

I am unsure about the format of the log lines or the relative distribution of Logins in the file, so what happens next depends on more information.

```
# If logins are rare?
grep Login /var/log/maillog | grep -f file_with_email_addrs | sort -u -k <column of email>

# If user count is small
grep -f file_with_email_addrs /var/log/maillog | awk '/Login/ {S[$<column of email>] = $0;} END {for (loop in S) {printf("%s\n",S[loop]);}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear, do you want to look for the last login for 'mail_address1' which is read from a file?

If so:

```
#/bin/bash
while read mail_address1;
do;
# Your command line here
cat /var/log/maillog | grep $mail_address1 | grep 'Login' | tail -1 >> result.txt
done; < file_with_email_adddrs
```

PS: I've changed the answer to reflect the suggestions (extremely valid ones) in the comments that advise against using a `for i in $(cat file)` style loop to loop through a file.

Comment: It worked for me when I excluded the semicolon.
Currently the command (cat log) is taking too much time since the log file is a very large one. Any idea to search the pattern 'email.txt' from the bottom of the log since it is checking the last login and I only need the last entry.

Comment: You shouldn't actually have to `cat log`. The better way would be `grep $mail_address1 log`. Also if you think it's taking too long, you might try and store the contents of the file in a temporary variable/array, one that you then use throughout the script. But how you can go about doing that depends on the format of your log.

Comment: [Don't use `for` to read a file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @dogbane: Totally agree. But in this case I would not even use while loop. Seems like it can be solved by egrep to grep the log file in parallel rather than repeatedly.

Comment: @LokiAstari Can you explain what you mean by parallel grepping/egrepping? I haven't come across this before.

Comment: Sure, you can even use `grep -f email.txt /var/log/maillog`. But the tricky part is getting the LAST login time for each email address.

Comment: If you decide to use a parallel grep or not really depends on the size of the log file and the number of users you are looking for. If it is small log file then it probably does not matter. But you probably don't want to rescan a huge log file many times.

Comment: Hi, Can you just let me know how can I replace the `for`? All the email addresses are available in the text file /root/email.txt each in a new line. Created a new text file /root/result.txt which will store the results. My script last_login.sh as below : 
**`#!/bin/bash for gg in $(cat /root/email.txt) do egrep $gg `/var/log  /maillog | grep 'Login' | tail -1 >> /root/result.txt` `done`**
result.txt will contain the last log for all the email address mentioned in email.txt file. Please let me know how can I improve the codes. I am still in learning phase. –

Comment: @Gopu see edit on how to replace the for. I think this is the recommended way of looping through a file.

Comment: @ffledgling : I have tried your updated script (after removing the semicolon in `do` ) but not working fine. I had to satisfy with the script which uses `for` . Anyway thanks for giving me some directions.